# Mi problema es que las filas en grid no se adaptan al elemento en altura

Tags: css, grid

muy buenas a todos. Mi problema es que las filas en grid no se adaptan al elemento en altura. En la imagen marque el espacio no deseado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EL DIV DE LA IMAGEN**

```
.hero__container{
    max-width: 800px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: max-content;
    --padding-container: 0;
    align-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hola @Zero 0, deberías facilitar un ejemplo completo y reproducible para poder entender el problema. En css el problema podría estar en una clase padre y nosotros no podríamos saberlo hasta poder ejecutarlo.